# Detect BLDC Direction From Hall Switch

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

How can you determine BLDC motor rotation direction as logic high/low by reading hall switches? Not using an MCU, just analog/digital/logic ICs.

Comment: When you say "hall switches" do you mean "hall effect sensors used to switch the commutation on a brushless DC motor"? If so, then it's the order that switches are turn on/off.

Comment: You will need a state machine, hopefully a digital one though some crude hacks with analog delays might work if you only care about a narrow range of speed.   This is near the territory where the effort of avoiding an MCU just isn't effective unless the volume will be huge or you are doing it as an intellectual exercise - even the IC's you'd probably end up using will be larger than the applicable MCUs.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: In the general case, you are correct. However if the signals from the Hall sensors overlap (like in a quadrature encoder), then a simple DFF is all you need to distinguish direction.

Comment: @Puffafish yes, exactly.

Comment: @ChrisStratton so I need to design a state machine, using like logic ICs, flip-flops, gates etc. which I am not keen on.

Comment: First you probably want to look at any two of the outputs on a scope while you rotate the motor by hand, and vibrate it in place.  Then you want to draw a diagram of the possible relationships and their desired result.  Then you can decide how you would personally prefer to implement this.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: A couple of flip-flops should do the trick whether the sensor outputs overlap or not? See my answer and let me know if I've missed something.

Comment: For goals that need no secondary rules, probably.  But you've drawn a chip that probably has at least 14 pins.  An MCU could have 8, maybe even 6.  It's also possible some quadrature encoder to step and direction chips might practically work watching two sensors only - and those are often in 8 pin packages though some may have some dependence on an external RC filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very similar to a 3-phase phase sequence detector application. The circuit of Figure 1 will get you most of the way to your requirements.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIYuH2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A single CD4013 dual D flip-flop will suffice.*

Q2 will pulse for an ABC rotation. It will remain off for an ACB rotation.

Comment: So, how can we get rotation direction, if we are using 120degree phase difference BLDC ?

Comment: What part of the answer do you not understand?

Comment: I understand this application and it works. But in a 120 degree phase BLDC, hall outputs are not the same. Logic high parts of outputs overlap. So, does not function the same.

Comment: That's probably the C input holding the outputs in the reset state. You'll need to add a one-shot or monostable to the C input to give a short reset pulse. The other option is to invert all of the signals. Would that cure the overlap?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this is by using a D type flip-flop. If the hall effects of your BLDC have 120° phase shift, connect one hall signal to the D input and the other on the CLK input.
The output will be low in a rotation direction and high in the other.
[image: LTSpice motor rotation direction simulation]

Comment: This is the right answer for 120°-duty-cycle Hall signals.

Answer (score 0):

If you search the literature (e.g: http://www.edn.com/design/sensors/4407580/1/Brushless-DC-Motors-Part-II--Control-Principles), you will find out that there are many copies of the same 'truth table' that give you exactly which switch should be turned on/off in your commutator based on the hall sensor state.

Once you have the truth tables, you can build a basic logic circuit from ANDs, ORs and inverter gates.